# How to count frequency of unique categorical values across multiple columns and group it by age

Tags: r

I have dataset like below:

```
Age      Monday Tuesday Wednesday
6-9        a     b        c
6-9        b     a        c
6-9        b     c        a
9-10       c     c        b
9-10       c     a        b
```

I want to find the total frequency of a,b,c across different age group using R as follows:

```
Age    a     b    c
6-9    3     3    3
9-10   1     2    3
```

Answer (score 1):

We can get the data in longer format, `count` them and convert to wide format again.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Age) %>%
  count(Age, value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n)

#  Age       a     b     c
#  <fct> <int> <int> <int>
#1 6-9       3     3     3
#2 9-10      1     2     3
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Age = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("6-9", 
"9-10"), class = "factor"), Monday = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), Tuesday = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), 
Wednesday = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: It giving me the following error message:Error: Column 1 must be named.
Use .name_repair to specify repair.
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
In addition: Warning message:
Factor `value` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na`

Comment: @fitrat Maybe you have `NA`'s in your data. Can you try `df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Age, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  count(Age, value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n)` ? If it doesn't work as well can you add `dput(df)` in your post.

Comment: Still giving the error: Error: Column 1 must be named.
Use .name_repair to specify repair.
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

Comment: The code works fine on my machine, have you tried to run it using @RonakShah s `df`?

Comment: @fitrat yes, please try using the data which I have provided does it give you the same error ?

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing with a different data set and it shows me these errors. However, the concept should be the same.

Comment: @fitrat In that case, you need to post a sample from your real dataframe as this gives the output on the sample that you have shared.

Answer (score 0):

Given the input data `df` as

```
df <- structure(list(Age = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("6-9", 
"9-10"), class = "factor"), Monday = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), Tuesday = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), 
Wednesday = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

then, the following may help if you plan to use `base R`:

```
# make a list of categorized by Age
lst <- split(df,df$Age)
# combine the list of data frame 
zlst <- do.call(rbind,sapply(seq_along(lst), function(k) cbind(data.frame(Age = names(lst)[k]), t(as.data.frame.factor(table(unlist(lst[[k]][,-1]))))),simplify = F))
# rename the row names 
rownames(zlst) <- seq(nrow(zlst))
```

which finally gives:

```
> zlst
   Age a b c
1  6-9 3 3 3
2 9-10 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can just use `table` from `base R`

```
table(rep(df$Age, 3), unlist(df[-1]))
#       a b c
#  6-9  3 3 3
#  9-10 1 2 3
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Age = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("6-9", 
"9-10"), class = "factor"), Monday = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), Tuesday = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), 
Wednesday = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: your code is giving me results. However, it does not show the labels like in this case a, b, c as the header of new data set. I would really appreciate if you kindly suggest me how can I get the labels of the data.

Comment: @fitrat  You can just convert to `data.frame` i.e. `as.data.frame.matrix(table(rep(df$Age, 3), unlist(df[-1])))`

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply. However, I still getting the labels as 1,2,3 instead of a,b,c.

Comment: @fitrat. Not clear what you meant.  I get the column names as 'a', 'b', c', ` `as.data.frame.matrix(table(rep(df$Age, 3), unlist(df[-1])))` with the data in the post.  If you have `factor` columns, please convert it to character i.e. `df[] <- lapply(df, is.character)`

Comment: Thank you so much. I was wondering is there any other way I can find the original labels of data corresponding to the numeric labels generated by r. I mean I just want to know say for example what does the label 1 represent? Is it a, b or c?

Comment: @fitrat. Can you post as a new question as all the solutions are posting the expected output in your post